# Convergent Validity with Multiple New Scales

Tags: correlation, validity, scale-construction

I am interested in creating a new scale in a field that is overwhelmingly understudied in the research literature.  I would like to test the convergent validity by modifying another survey instrument from a related, but not identical, field of research.  Is it still possible to get useful information about convergent validity based on correlations between two essentially new scales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes. If you create two new tests that are supposed to measure the same thing, it's helpful to know that their scores are closely related, because if they weren't, that would indicate that something is probably wrong.